# NodeMCU cannot use uart 1 - Lua

Tags: lua, esp8266, uart, nodemcu

i'm using NodeMCU v2 devkit with ESP8266 module. I'm programming in Lua, and i want to use alternative pins to transmit data through UART. I'm aware that UART 1 pins can only transmit, not receive data. So in my code i'm trying to change pins assignment using

```
uart.alt(1)
```

but i got an error

```
attempt to call field 'alt' (a nil value)
```

No matter what i do, error still apears until i got this line in my code. I also tried to use it with uart.setup with first parameter 1 to define uart 1 but then another error appears:

```
uart.setup(1, 9600, 8, 0, 1, 1)
```

error:

```
stdin:1 uart 1 does not exist
```

I'm asking for help because maybe i'm doing something wrong and the solution is easy or maybe there is a problem with uart 1 in Lua. I saw many topics but advices were only connected with firmware. I tried many versions and problem is still there.

details from documentation here : http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/uart/

Comment: many versions is not very specific. which firmeware version do you use? if uart.alt is nil you either somehow assigned nil to it or it never existed in your build (which is more likely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uart.alt` was [added to the firmware](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/commit/b2345857e9c50a40a8bd2d11bfb473f62dec21fe#diff-2b6d55a18186bcb1e1f0a603751921ff) on Nov 28, 2015.

So, with near certainty you're using a firmware from before that. I suggest you [build and flash](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/build/) a recent NodeMCU binary, one the matches what you find in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for specific date. I noticed that i was using nodemcu_integer_0.9.6-dev_20150704 which is older than expected. I was using it because on this firmware i was able to do everything i needed except uart things. I tried before custom builds https://nodemcu-build.com/ but the output in ESPlorer was like ş®\*P6µUH5�Y%. So basically strange chars and i was not able to do anything with module. Programming was not able, I'm wondering why i cannot use custom builds. Problem exist for both master and dev branch.

Comment: I made some tests and i noticed that module can be programmed with latest firmware and uart.alt and uart.setup not generating errors anymore. I still did not achieve what i wanted using uart 1 but this is a question for another topic. For now i can say that errors connected with uart are solved thanks to your answer and latest firmware.

Comment: NodeMCU has been using 115'200bps by default for a long time, while ESPlorer may be using 9'600bps by default. That's likely the reason you were seeing gibberish. See https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/ for details.